# Downloading static snapshot of a single web page with current states and localstorage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

While it is very common to download/save a webpage as a complete HTML page using the browser's built-in functionality or a web scraping app, I am curious to know if there exists any way to scrap/download/take a snapshot of a page at its current state with all the existing loaded data including local storage/caches.

For example, we can assume that when YouTube loads a video even if we lose the internet connection we can play the video until refreshed. In the same way, can I download such a page that will mimic a page with a lost connection?

Comment: you might search around for a browser extension/plugin that would do this.  I found one pretty quickly called "Single File".  Not sure if it saves temp/cache files, though.